# How to create an interface to record an attendance using PHP, MYSQL and other language?

Tags: php, html, mysql, interface, record

I have created few tables such as date table which records the date and time of the attendance recorded, student table which records details of students and status which records present, absent or late.

I want to create a interface where a teacher can record the attendance easily and where MYSQL PHP language can be used.

I have being able to echo out all the list of the students from a certain class taught by specific teacher. Now I want to let the teacher to use checkbox system to select or deselect and submit and directly update into the database.

Can you please help me how can I start this process?

If you want more information then please let me know.

I want to create a interface such as attendance recording interface where I have create a table which involves student_id as foreign key from student table. Then a status table that records present, late or absent status and a date & time record that records the date and time the record was added.

When a user selects the checkboxes of three different types and clicks Submit then the PHP will send this information to the MYSQL saying Tim is present but Ashley is late recognized with their student_id so it means it will update the student’s record however I was think of using insert query command rather than update because new records might be added everyday.

So the formula or the query could be SELECT the checkboxes and insert status of the student WHERE student_id = the chosen column.

I am struggling on the right query to work out and do I have to use JavaScript to make it work or use a PHP function?

Comment: I think, that a good start would be reading some about relational databases: https://www.google.com/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=Zf-nU-OFCuno7Abi4oDACw&gws_rd=ssl#q=relational+databases+mysql.

Comment: Your question is too broad: we usually expect people to have a go at their problem first, and then ask if they are stuck. If you have zero knowledge of php, you should first try a tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand how POST/GET resquests work (for interfacing between HTML and PHP side), and then how to call a MySQL request from PHP. Here you have some usefull examples:

GET/POST requests:
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp

Interfacing MySQL with PHP (I recommend read all sections, intro, connection to database etc)

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_intro.asp

MySQL insertion to database (this is the 'record' part you are looking for):

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp

Answer (score 0):

Basically what you're asking for - "How can I make a nice slick HTML/CSS interface that uses PHP/MySQL on the backend to perform these operations - CREATE, RETRIEVE, UPDATE, DELETE"

Things you can learn in sequence -

1. Acccessing MySQL DB from PHP and populate into HTML table, you can generate the checkboxes too.
2. Make the table look cool with some CSS
3. And communicate between the server and client side using form submissions, using GET/POST

This is just a general guidance to get you started. Do not land up using frameworks or libraries immediately if you wan't to be in this field in the long run.

Welcome to webdev. :)